# How to reduce the length of this code written with python.turtle?

Tags: python, forms, reduce, figure, python-turtle

I need help reducing the total length or lines of this code written with python.turtle. I need to have the same output and just reduce the length of the lines if possible using other functions! Here is the code:

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(5)
#external form
t.pen(pensize=2, pencolor="blue")
t.forward(400)
t.right(120)
t.forward(200)
t.pen(pensize=2, pencolor="purple")
t.right(120)
t.forward(200)
t.right(60)
t.forward(200)
t.left(120)
t.forward(200)
t.right(60)
t.forward(200)
t.left(120)
t.forward(200)
t.right(60)
t.forward(200)
t.left(120)
t.forward(200)
t.right(60)
t.forward(200)
t.left(120)
t.forward(200)
t.right(60)
t.forward(200)
t.left(120)
t.forward(200)
t.right(60)
t.forward(200)
t.penup()
t.goto(0,0)
t.pendown()
t.pen(pensize=2, pencolor="blue")
t.left(180)
t.forward(400)
t.right(120)
t.forward(200)
t.pen(pensize=2, pencolor="purple")
t.right(60)
t.forward(200)
t.pen(pensize=2, pencolor="blue")
t.right(60)
t.backward(200)
t.forward(800)
t.right(120)
t.forward(200)
t.backward(200)
t.left(120)
t.backward(800)
t.left(60)
t.forward(200)
t.penup()
t.goto(0,0)
t.pendown()
t.left(60)
t.forward(400)
t.right(120)
t.forward(200)
t.backward(200)
t.right(60)
t.forward(800)
t.right(120)
t.forward(200)
#inner figure
t.penup()
t.goto(-45, -230)
t.pendown()
t.pen(pensize=4, pencolor="yellow")
t.right(120)
t.forward(90)
t.circle(5,90)
t.forward(90)
t.left(90)
t.forward(105)
t.back(110)
t.left(-90)
t.forward(15)
t.left(90)
t.forward(110)
t.left(90)
t.forward(15)
t.left(90)
t.forward(5)
t.right(90)
t.forward(90)
t.circle(5,90)
t.penup()
t.goto(-25,-118)
t.pendown()
t.left(90)
t.forward(8)
t.circle(-10,90)
t.forward(30)
t.circle(-10,90)
t.forward(8)
t.penup()
t.goto(-25,-215)
t.pendown()
t.left(180)
t.forward(65)
t.penup()
t.goto(0,-215)
t.pendown()
t.forward(65)
t.penup()
t.goto(25,-215)
t.pendown()
t.forward(65)
```

I have tried very much but couldn't have same output. I tried to reduce the code by using for in range and other functions but like I said couldn't have the same out. by the way I am a beginner!

Comment: i haven't seen the image, but if the drawing has repeating shapes, you can factor the code for those shapes out into their own functions to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look for patterns of function calls and make some utility functions of your own to work at a higher level of abstraction.  For example, you are tracing lines by moving a certain distance then changing angle in series of Move-turn-move-turn...  So, if you had a function that allows you to specify a list of alternating moves and turns, consecutive line tracings could be made with a single function call.

Same thing for the "GOTOs".  you are lifting the pen, moving to an absolute position and putting the pen down again.  These 3 steps could be combined in a single function of your own.

Here's an example:

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(5)

# trace a line composed of multiple segments alternating a forward move
# and a right turn.  (backward and left turns to be expressed as negatives)
def TRACE(distance,angle=0,*more):
    t.forward(distance)
    t.right(angle)
    if more: TRACE(*more)
    
# function to move the turtle to a specific position without tracing
def JUMPTO(x,y):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.pendown()
```

The whole drawing can then be expressed more concisely:

```
#external form    
t.pen(pensize=2, pencolor="blue")
TRACE(400,120,200)    
t.pen(pencolor="purple")
TRACE(0,120, 200,60,200, *[-120,200,60,200]*5)

JUMPTO(0,0)
t.pen(pencolor="blue")
TRACE(0,-180,400,120,200)
t.pen(pencolor="purple")
TRACE(0,60,200)
t.pen(pencolor="blue")
TRACE(0,60,-200, 0,800,120,200, 0,-200,-120,-800, -60,200)

JUMPTO(0,0)
TRACE(0,-60,400,120,200,0,-200,60,800,120,200)

#inner figure
JUMPTO(-45,-230)
t.pen(pensize=4, pencolor="yellow")
TRACE(0,120,90)
t.circle(5,90)
TRACE(90,-90,105,0,-110,90,15,-90,110,-90,15,-90,5,90,90)
t.circle(5,90)

JUMPTO(-25,-118)
TRACE(0,-90,8)
t.circle(-10,90)
TRACE(30)
t.circle(-10,90)
TRACE(8)

JUMPTO(-25,-215)
TRACE(0,-180,65)    
JUMPTO(0,-215)
TRACE(65)    
JUMPTO(25,-215)
TRACE(65)
```

To move backward or turn left, specify negative distances/angles.

When you need to make two consecutive movements (e.g. forward, then backward), place a zero angle in between.

When you need to change the angle as the first step (e.g. after drawing a circle or changing pen colour), start with a distance of zero.

The `*[-120,200,60,200]*5` expression repeats the `-120,200,60,200` sequence five times as if you had written `-120,200,60,200,-120,200,60,200,-120,200,60,200,-120,200,60,200,-120,200,60,200`

*Notes:*

- When designing your functions, make sure to give them a single purpose that has a meaning.  For example, TRACE() only draws a series of line segments. It does not set the pen colour. This makes it more reusable because you don't change the colour every time and that would give two "unrelated" responsibilities to that function.  It also makes naming the functions easier. A double purpose function would end up needing a composite name (TRACECOLOR, COLORTHENTRACE, TRACEWITHCOLOR, ...) which is a telltale sign that some unwieldy coupling is going on.
- I used uppercase names for the functions so they would stand out in the revised code.  That is only for the sake of emphasis. I am not suggesting that you should name functions with all uppercase.

[EDIT] If you group the tracing by colour and use smaller symmetrical segment sequences for the blue lines, the code could even be a bit shorter:

```
#external form
t.pen(pensize=2,pencolor="blue")
TRACE(0,-60,*[400,120,200,180,200,-120,400,120]*5,400,120,200,120)
t.pen(pencolor="purple")
TRACE(200,60,200, *[-120,200,60,200]*5)
    
#inner figure
t.pen(pensize=4, pencolor="yellow")
JUMPTO(-45,-230)
TRACE(90)
t.circle(5,90)
TRACE(90,-90,105,0,-110,90,15,-90,110,-90,15,-90,5,90,90)
t.circle(5,90)

JUMPTO(-25,-118)
TRACE(0,-90,8)
t.circle(-10,90)
TRACE(30)
t.circle(-10,90)
TRACE(8)

JUMPTO(-25,-215)
TRACE(0,-180,65)    
JUMPTO(0,-215)
TRACE(65)    
JUMPTO(25,-215)
TRACE(65)
```

To avoid backtracking over lines for the external form, you could repeat a partial pattern that has two blue segments and two purple segments:

```
for _ in range(6):  # repeat 6 times
    JUMPTO(0,0)
    t.pen(pensize=2,pencolor="blue")
    TRACE(400,120,200,120)
    t.pen(pencolor="purple")
    TRACE(200,60,200)
```